# Using brewer2mpl diverging colormap with matplotlib, gamma gives poor results with values different than 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Playing with colormaps in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41075/12102) I was introduced to `brewer2mpl` in comments. For the diverging map (with zero in the middle) I noticed that gamma is implemented to work in a naive way and so gives unexpected<sup>†</sup> results when it is not equal to 1.  The neutral tone meant to represent zero slides around so that values near zero are blue with gamma = 0.5 and orang when gamma = 1.5

Is there anyway to make a gamma-like parameter that operates symmetrically around zero in `matplotlib` or `brewer2mpl` or do I just have to do it manually somehow by raising `np.abs(u)` to some power then re-normalizing and re-introducing the sign?

<sup>†</sup>expected behavior would be to apply gamma symmetrically about zero; at least that's what *I had* expected.

[image: divergent colormap with brewer2mpl and gamma not equal to 1 gives bad results]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import brewer2mpl

Re = 6378137. # meters
J2 = 1.7555E+25 # m^5/s^2
hw = 400
x = np.linspace(-2.5*Re, 2.5*Re, 2*hw+1)
x, z = np.meshgrid(x, x)
r = np.sqrt(x**2 + z**2)
u = J2 * r**-5 * 0.5 * (3*z**2 - r**2)
u[r<Re] = np.nan

if True:
    umax = np.nanmax(np.abs(u))
    bmap = brewer2mpl.get_map('RdBu', 'Diverging', 9)
    gammas = 0.5, 1, 1.5
    plt.figure()
    for i, gamma in enumerate(gammas):
        cmap = bmap.get_mpl_colormap(N=100, gamma=gamma)
        plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
        plt.imshow(u, cmap=cmap, vmin=-umax, vmax=umax)
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.title('gamma = ' + str(gamma))
        plt.plot([hw, hw], [0.3*hw, 1.7*hw], '-k')
        plt.xlim(0, 2*hw+1)
        plt.ylim(0, 2*hw+1)
    plt.suptitle("Earth's geopotential's J2 component", fontsize=16)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You can create two colormaps, one from red to white, one from white to blue. Then apply gamma to each of those. Finally get the colors from those colormaps and create a new one with the combined colors.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That sounds very promising! Someone more knowledgable than I can perhaps. `cmap` doesn't seem to have an .`__add__` method and I can't figure out how to add the `.N` colors of one to the `.N` colors of another.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two colormaps, one from red to white, one from white to blue. Then apply gamma to each of those. Finally get the colors from those colormaps and create a new one with the combined colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from copy import copy

cmap = plt.get_cmap("RdBu", lut=256)
# Create two new colormaps, each with one half of the original
cmap_lower = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", cmap(np.arange(0,128)))
cmap_upper = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", cmap(np.arange(128,256)))
gammas = [1, 0.5, 1.5]


fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(8,5))

for ax, gamma in zip(axs, gammas):
    # copy each colormap and set the respective gamma
    cm1 = copy(cmap_lower)
    cm1.set_gamma(gamma)
    cm2 = copy(cmap_upper)
    cm2.set_gamma(gamma)
    # get the colors from the each
    colors = np.concatenate((cm1(np.arange(0,256)), cm2(np.arange(0,256))), axis=0) 
    this_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)

    im = ax.imshow(np.arange(300).reshape(30,10), cmap=this_cmap)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f"gamma={gamma}")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Okay I'll have a look today.

Comment: This is close, but I haven't accepted yet because "expected behavior would be to apply gamma symmetrically about zero" which is harder because `np.sign()` has to be split off and gamma applied to the absolute value of each half separately, then the two joined somehow. *Some day* I hope to implement that based on this answer, but if you have he time and inclination and want to do that here then I can accept. Thanks!